# Nested options doesn't print all path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

When I click on an option, the select only shows the option value. Is there a way in **angular** to show the full path of a select with nested options?

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="A">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

For example if I select option 5, the standard select will show only value "5". I want "B / 5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by directive,

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

        app.directive('getVal', function () {
            return function (scope, ele) {
                var element = angular.element(ele);

                element.change(function (e) {
                    var y = element.val();
                    var selected = angular.element(':selected', element);
                    var optionLabel = selected.closest('optgroup').attr('label');

                    angular.element('#output').text(optionLabel + ' / ' + y);
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <select get-val>
            <optgroup label="A">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="B">
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will output "**B / 5**" if you select 5.

Comment: @StefanoVollono oops, sorry some typo errors,  check http://codepen.io/swapnil-patil/pen/rOJLPx

Comment: @StefanoVollono Will it useful for you ?

Comment: Hi Swapnil Patil, your pen works correctly but i would the result inside of select, not outside

Comment: @StefanoVollono What do you exactly mean by inside of select ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know how to do it properly, but I've come up with a workaround.

```js
$(function()
{
   $('select').change(changed);
});

function changed()
{   

    var y = $(this).val();
    
    var x = $($($($(this).find("option")).filter(function() {return $(this).text() === y;})).parent()).attr('label');
    console.log(x);
    
    $('#test').text(x + ' / ' + y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <optgroup label="A">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div id="test"></div>
```

To break it down, we assign the selected value to variable y. Then we take the select input and find its children `$(this).find("option")` then we filter it looking for the one which has text is the same as the chosen one `$($(this).find("option")).filter(function() {return $(this).text() === y;})` and then we select its parent (the optgroup) and then its the value of its label.

Comment: Hi @Fiodor but i need to use angular and the result must be injected into select, not outside.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed the angularjs tag. I don't know angular, and I don't really know how to inject it into select. I mean, you could do that, but not without changing the text in <option> field itself.